# How to combine two columns data of same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, sql-null

Consider that I have a stored procedure resulting in following result.

Stored Procedure Code

```
DECALRE @myTab TABLE(
  Id int NOT NULL,
  Name nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
  Scale1 int,
  Scale2 int
)

Insert into @myData(Id,Name,Scale1,Scale2)
Select 
I.Id,
I.Name,
S1.Amount,
S2.Amount
From Information I 
Left Join Scale1 S1 on I.Scale1Id = S1.Id
Left Join Scale2 S2 on I.Scale2Id = S2.Id


Select * From @myTab
```

Here is Resulting Table.

```
+------+----------+--------+---------+
| ID   | NAME     | Scale1 | Scale2  |
+------+----------+--------+---------+
|    1 | Ramesh   |   NULL | 1230    |
|    2 | Khilan   |   1560 | NULL    |
|    3 | kaushik  |   3000 | NULL    |
|    3 | kaushik  |   1500 | NULL    |
|    4 | Chaitali |   2060 | NULL    |
|    5 | Hardik   |   NULL | 1569    |
|    6 | Komal    |   NULL | 2548    |
|    7 | Muffy    |   NULL | 1256    |
+------+----------+--------+---------+
```

Now I want to combine column Scale1 and Scale 2 and make it single column Scale, that has no null Data, like following example.

```
+------+----------+--------+
| ID   | NAME     | Scale  |  
+------+----------+--------+ 
|    1 | Ramesh   |   1230 |  
|    2 | Khilan   |   1560 | 
|    3 | kaushik  |   3000 |  
|    3 | kaushik  |   1500 |  
|    4 | Chaitali |   2060 |  
|    5 | Hardik   |   1569 |   
|    6 | Komal    |   2548 |  
|    7 | Muffy    |   1256 |  
+------+----------+--------+
```

How can I achieve this please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()`:

```
select 
    i.id,
    i.name,
    coalesce(s1.amount, s2.amount) scale
from information i 
left join scale1 s1 on i.scale1id = s1.id
left join scale2 s2 on i.scale2id = s2.id
```

This gives priority to the value in the first `left join`ed table, and falls back on the other one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `coalesce()`

```
Select 
I.Id,
I.Name,
coalesce(S1.Amount,S2.Amount) as amount
From Information I 
Left Join Scale1 S1 on I.Scale1Id = S1.Id
Left Join Scale2 S2 on I.Scale2Id = S2.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach is `ISNULL()` (and it's an additional option if there are values in both `s1.Amount` and `s2.Amount` columns):

```
Insert into @myData (Id,Name,Scale1,Scale2)
Select 
   I.Id,
   I.Name,
   ISNULL(S1.Amount, 0) + ISNULL(S2.Amount, 0) AS Amount
From Information I 
Left Join Scale1 S1 on I.Scale1Id = S1.Id
Left Join Scale2 S2 on I.Scale2Id = S2.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . It seems like you want to unpivot the data:

```
select t.id, t.name, v.scale
from @mytable t cross apply
     (values (t.scale1), (t.scale2)) v(scale)
where v.scale is not null;
```